# Submit via Enter (specific Submit Submit Name)

Tags: php, javascript, html

This submitenter function is floating around the internet, apparently it is from O'Reilly's. Good job, however, I need it to POST a specific submit value. (Submit button is named submitReport). I have tried

```
 myfield.form.submitReport();
```

but it doesn't work. I don't really have any ideas about what to do at this point. I am willing to bet that the answer is straightforward but I am stumped, I'd love any suggestions.

```
 function submitenter(myfield,e)
            {
            var keycode;
            if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
            else if (e) keycode = e.which;
            else return true;

            if (keycode == 13)
               {
               myfield.form.submit();
               return false;
               }
            else
               return true;
            }
```

Here is the submit button I am trying to have it enter for me.

The script must produce 'submitReport', there is a PHP function looking for $_POST['submitReport'], this is because there are a few forms on this page.

```
<form name= "Insert" onsubmit="return validate(this)" method="post" action="">
<textarea name ="link"></textarea>
<textarea name ="country"></textarea>
<textarea name ="province"></textarea>

<input 
    type ="submit" 
    style="visibility:hidden" 
    name ="submitReport" 
    value =''
> 
</form>
```

Comment: Please post your form HTML (or post it to jsfiddle.net and post the url)

Comment: All I had to do was change where it says submit to text in the input tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a hidden field to the form that is named submitReport.

Comment: Hah. Alright, kinda hacky but it sounds like it'll work. Off to test it!

Answer (score 0):

You only have a problem in the first place because you are using textarea elements where it seems input elements would be more appropriate.

If users recognise the textarea as a textarea, they don't expect pressing enter or return to submit the form so you are breaking the usuability of the page. If you are making the textarea elements look like inupts, then use inputs and no javascript is required to submit the form.